# solving separable differential equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am to solve the following differential equation using separation of variables
$$f'(x)+2x[f^2(x)-f(x)]=0$$
So far my approach was:
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}+2x[f^2(x)-f(x)]=0$$
$$\frac{df(x)}{dx}+f^2(x)-f(x)=\frac{1}{2x}$$
$$df(x)+f^2(x)-f(x)=\frac{1}{2x}dx$$

However I am unsure of how to continue/integrate over the left hand side. 
Any tips would be greatly appreciated!

I apologise in advance for any trivial mistakes I might have made, as I am not very familiar with differential equations yet.
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your mistake was asumming
$$
f' + 2x(f^2-f) =0 \implies f' +f^2-f = \frac{1}{2x}
$$
this is wrong.
Your equation is actually
$$
\frac{1}{f^2-f}\frac{df}{dx} = -2x
$$
I assume you can take it from here.

Answer (score 1):

i would write $$\frac{df(x)}{dx}=-2x(f^2(x)-f(x))$$ and from here we get
$$\frac{df}{f^2-f}=-2xdx$$